# Using flex graph component in java

Tags: java, apache-flex

Is there any flex graph cerating api for java. So that we can create graph by using java code.
If yes from where did i start from?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a java API to create flex charts.

In my opinion there are 2 options:

1. Write a Flex client that connects to a Java Rest service/Soap service/RPC service to get charting data
2. Use Java script (from GWT for example) and pass data to the Flex client through the ExternalInterface API

In any case you will have to write a custom Flex client to do what you describe.

There are some open source charting libraries available when you look for them, however they will all work in one of the two ways described above.

Cheers